# How to display a span based on a invalid input SASS

Tags: reactjs, sass

im using SASS and i would like to display an error span when the input is invalid, can this be done using just SASS?

this is the input div:

```
const FormInput = (props) => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const { label, errorMessage, onChange, id, ...inputProps } = props;

  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    setFocused(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="formInput">
      <span>{errorMessage}</span>
      <input
        {...inputProps}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={handleFocus}
        onFocus={() =>
          inputProps.name === "confirmPassword" && setFocused(true)
        }
        focused={focused.toString()}
        className="Input"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and this is the SASS file i can change the border color of the input field it self but idk how to change the display  of the span from none to block when the input is invalid

```
.formInput {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90%;
  height: max-content;
  span {
    color: red;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
  }
  .Input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: var(--inputColor);
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 20px;
    &:invalid[focused="true"] {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
}
```

the inputs are validated using html pattern with regex and required attribute
like this:

```
 const inputs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "email",
      type: "email",
      placeholder: "Email",
      errorMessage: "It should be a valid email address!",
      label: "Email",
      required: true,
    },
{
      id: 2,
      name: "password",
      type: "password",
      placeholder: "Password",
      errorMessage:
        "Password should be 8-20 characters and include at least 1 letter, 1 number and 1 special character!",
      label: "Password",
      pattern: `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/`,
      required: true,
    },
]
```

Comment: One alternative is to pass to the span the valid prop and change its class dynamically depending on the valid/invalid state of the input: `<span className={``${inputProps.invalid ? 'show' : 'hide'}``}`

Comment: I forgot to say that the inputs are validated using html pattern with regex and required attribute so they are not a prop

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, first you have to make sure that the span is  placed after the input like this

```
  <div className="formInput">
      <input
        {...inputProps}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={handleFocus}
        onFocus={() =>
          inputProps.name === "confirmPassword" && setFocused(true)
        }
        focused={focused.toString()}
        className="Input"
      />
      <span>{errorMessage}</span>
    </div>
```

and then add this to the SCSS file:

```
.Input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: var(--inputColor);
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 20px;
    &:invalid[focused="true"] {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    &:invalid[focused="true"] {
      display: block;
      **~ { 
        span {
          display: block;
        }**
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do it with pseudo class like the following example, you need to put the span tag just next to the input tag, here I'm using a text input element but you can change it as you require:

```
HTML
<input name="question1" type="text" value="prefixed value" required> <span></span>

CSS
input[type="text"]:invalid + span:after {
    content: '✖';
}
    
input[type="text"]:valid + span:after {
    content: '✓';
}
```

Here the content will change if the person leave this input field empty.